I am getting error while calling setShowCart(true) function on button click in Navbar.jsx
This is my code and I am getting error while calling setShowCart(true) function in Navbar.jsx.I don't understand how to resolve this.
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link';
import {AiOutlineShopping} from 'react-icons/ai';
import { Cart } from '.';


const Navbar = ({ showCart, setShowCart }) => {
  return (
    <div className='navbar-container'> 
    <p className='logo'>
      <Link href="/">JSM headphones</Link>

    </p>
    <button type="button" className="cart-icon" onClick={() => setShowCart(true)}>
      <AiOutlineShopping/>
      <span className='cart-item-qty'>1</span>
    </button>
    {showCart && <Cart />}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar;


import React from 'react'
import Head from 'next/head';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Footer from './Footer';


const Layout = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div className='layout'>
      <Head>
        <title>E-commerce  Store</title>
        </Head>
        <header>
          <Navbar/>
        </header>
        <main className='main-container'>
        {children}
        </main>
        <footer>
          <Footer/>
        </footer>

 
    </div>
  )
}

export default Layout

My error is this for Navbar.jsx function.Can anyone advice me how to solve error? error is below in screenshot like this

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Event handlers cannot be passed to Client Component props.
  <button type="button" className=... onClick={function} children=...>
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^
If you need interactivity, consider converting part of this to a Client Component.


I read your code and find an error in Layout component.
You need to pass setShowCard props to Navbar.
const Layout = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div className='layout'>
      <Head>
        <title>E-commerce  Store</title>
        </Head>
        <header>
          {/* <Navbar/> */}
          <Navbar showCart={showCart} setShowCart={setShowCart} />
        </header>
        <main className='main-container'>
        {children}
        </main>
        <footer>
          <Footer/>
        </footer>

 
    </div>
  )
}

You need to define showCart and setShowCart as state or receive from parent as props.
The second solution is to use the default props for Navbar component.
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link';
import {AiOutlineShopping} from 'react-icons/ai';
import { Cart } from '.';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


const Navbar = ({ showCart, setShowCart }) => {
  return (
    <div className='navbar-container'> 
    <p className='logo'>
      <Link href="/">JSM headphones</Link>

    </p>
    <button type="button" className="cart-icon" onClick={() => setShowCart(true)}>
      <AiOutlineShopping/>
      <span className='cart-item-qty'>1</span>
    </button>
    {showCart && <Cart />}
    </div>
  )
}

Navbar.propTypes = {
    showCart: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    setShowCart: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

Navbar.defaultProps = {
   showCart: false,
   setShowCart: () => {}
}

export default Navbar;

